# Como saber o tipo de uma variável no Kotlin?

Tags: variáveis, tipagem, kotlin

Qual a função para saber o tipo de uma variável?

ex:

```
var a = "teste"
print(a.type())
```

output:

```
String
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconheço algo em Kotlin que pegue o tipo da [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), mas nem parece ser o que deseja. E pra falar a verdade isto raramente é necessário porque no código fica claro qual é o tipo. Não é possível saber em tempo de execução o tipo de uma variável porque neste momento a variável não existe.

É possível pegar o tipo do objeto em questão e o seu código parece indicar que é isto que deseja. Aí é só usar reflexão, algo assim:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a = "teste"
    print(a.javaClass.name)
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/u0dm2Q). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cpnvuchz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/GetObjectName.kt).

Só pense bem porque está querendo fazer isto, provavelmente não precisa e está criando um código convoluto. A pergunta e comentário abaixo indicam que não precisa desta informação, mas quer saber outra coisa. Seria melhor estudar sobre tipagem antes de prosseguir sobre isto.

Comment: Eu estava querendo saber como pegar o tipo de uma variavel readLine() em especifico, mas eu fui testar da maneira que vc me falou e ela não funcionou, sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: `readLine()` não é uma variável. Não funcionou porque você fez algo errado, mas agora está mais claro que sequer precisa o que está querendo fazer. Você já sabe o tipo da variável olhando para seu código, não precisa perguntar em temp ode execução, e mesmo o objeto também sabe porque se não faz herança, se não está usando *generics* , não tem como não saber, esqueça essa ideia de pegar o tipo de alguma coisa, porque ele já está no seu código, é irrelevante fazer isto, está olhando para o problema errado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a reflexão para fazer isso:

```
val widget = ...
println("${widget::class.qualifiedName}") // Com o nome do pacote
println("${widget::class.simpleName}")    // Apenas o nome da classe
```

Para testar um tipo específico, você pode usar o operador `is`.

```
if(widget is Widget) {
   // ...
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165143/)

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo para teste e analise

```
val obj: Double = 5.0

System.out.println(obj.javaClass.name)                 // double
System.out.println(obj.javaClass.kotlin)               // class kotlin.Double
System.out.println(obj.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName) // kotlin.Double
```